# LINQ how to return group by as List?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have a datatable that is populated with 2 columns, DateTime and Data. I have been able to group the list using:

```
var dates = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x["DateTime"]).ToShortDateString());
```

The conversion is to drop the "time" portion of the datetime as I only want 1 date per day so I can iterate over it.

I can see during debugging that the LINQ works out as I intended, but I have almost no experience in LINQ and I do not know how to return these results in a way that is iterable.

Below that LINQ statement I have:

```
foreach (string date in dates) {
    string dummy2 = "";
}
```

with an error on `foreach` that says

`Cannot convert type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string, System.Data.DataRow>' to 'string'`

The goal here is to return a list of just the unique dates which I can iterate over to perform additional processing/LINQ queries on the datatable

Comment: `date.Key` is the date string (`Key` is the property used for grouping)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list of unique dates, you can do something like this.

```
var dates = table.Select(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x["DateTime"]).ToShortDateString()).Distinct();
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer since it removes the unnecessary grouping. Now I have ```var dates = table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Convert.ToDateTime((x["DateTime"])).Date).Distinct().ToList();``` which is giving me a list of DateTime's

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the dates, then you don't need to use `GroupBy`, you can use `Distinct`. Also, you can get them as a `DateTime` object by just grabbing the `Date` property, which has a zeroed-out time component:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> distinctDates = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x["DateTime"]).Date)
    .Distinct();
```

If you want the groups but are just trying to select the date strings from them, then you want to use the `Key` property of the groups, which is the property that was used to group the items:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, System.Data.DataRow>> dates = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x["DateTime"]).ToShortDateString());

List<string> distinctDates = dates.Select(date => date.Key).ToList();
```

As a side note, unless you know the data type being returned by something, you might avoid using `var`, since that was hiding the fact that `dates` wasn't a collection of strings.

Answer (score 1):

that's happening since as the error says you're trying to loop in a dictionary:

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string, System.Data.DataRow>' to 'string'
```

what you can do is add to your `GroupBy` statement a `select` portion:

```
var dates = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x["DateTime"]).ToShortDateString()).Select(x=> x.date);
```

Comment: .date is not valid on an IGrouping.

Comment: This is helpful information for what I need to do now with the rest of my program